# how do i convert binary number into integer without making it positive

Tags: python, binary

i need a function that will convert binary with sign to integer.

```
int("1010",2) 
#this will be converted to 10 instead of -6 - 
# i want a fucnction that will convert it into -6
```

Answer (score 5):

You may use the `bitstring` module:

```
from bitstring import Bits
nr = Bits(bin='1010')
print(nr.int) # .int here acts as signed integer. If you use .uint it will print 10
```

Comment: I don't see `bitstring` in the standard python libraries. It's probably something that has to be installed separately with `pip install bitstring`.

Comment: @darksky you're right, you have to install this module in the IDE or via terminal

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way to do this, but it's easy enough to adjust the positive value by checking the first bit of your string.

```
def signed_bin(s):
    n = int(s, 2)
    if s[0] == '1':
        n -= 1<<len(s)
    return n

# test

w = 4
for i in range(1<<w):
    s = '{:0{}b}'.format(i, w)
    print(i, s, signed_bin(s))
```

**output**

```
 0 0000 0
1 0001 1
2 0010 2
3 0011 3
4 0100 4
5 0101 5
6 0110 6
7 0111 7
8 1000 -8
9 1001 -7
10 1010 -6
11 1011 -5
12 1100 -4
13 1101 -3
14 1110 -2
15 1111 -1
```

Answer (score -1):

According to answer of [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6032016/john-smith), You may also use `BitArray` to do this task :

```
>>> from bitstring import BitArray
>>> b = BitArray(bin='1010')
>>> b.int
-6
```

Comment: This is virtually identical to [the answer posted by John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45621114/4014959) 8 minutes ago.

Comment: It's a duplicate answer though

Comment: How ? I use `BitArray` here .

Comment: @Md.RezwanulHaque the only difference of `BitArray` is that it is mutable. It's in fact a subclass of `Bits`.